# GET json response from URL

Tags: javascript, json, api

I understand that this question asked MANY times, but I can't figure out how to make it work in my circumstances

It is a simple thing. I have url = WWW, but opening it in web browser you will see JSON.

I need to use JavaScript to get this JSON from URL and use it further.

```
<script>
var data;

$.getJSON("http://XXX?callback=?").done(function( data ) {
    console.log('hello', data);
    data = data;
    initMap();
});

function initMap() {    

  //response from URL have to be used here
  data.forEach((item) => {

    });
}

    </script>
```

DOes anyone know how to solve it? Ideally by using ASYNC

This is FULL CODE:

```
    <script>
// data from server
$.getJSON("http://XXX?callback=?").then(function( data ) {
    console.log('hello', data);
    initMap(data);
});

// place you want to initially center the map on
const center = {
  lat: 51.509865,
  lng: -0.118092
}

function initMap(data) {
  // set up map
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: center.lat, lng: center.lng}
  });

  // loop over data from server
  data.forEach((item) => {
    // build a infowindow add dump the product table into it.
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: item.Products
    });

    // add and position the marker on the map
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: item.Latitude, lng: item.Longitude},
      map: map,
      title: item.StoreName
    });

    // and event for opening the infowindow
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

</script>
```

JSON Looks like this :

```
[
    {
        "LatLan": "-3,22",
        "Latitude": 22,
        "Longitude": -3,
        "StoreName": "XXX",
        "Products": "XXX"
    },
    // carry on...
]
```

Comment: So you've seen that there are plenty of existing questions about this, and presumably read them. Please explain what is different about *your* case than all the ones you just read.

Comment: What, if any, errors are you getting?

Comment: @BlackICE Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined,  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: @IMSoP I do the same as was priviously, but some of the methods are depricated and the others do not work..... simply can not make my code work.... and have nNO idea WHY

Comment: Provide a _real_ URL.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir API contains sensitive data ... is it necessary? if yes, will need to recreate API with sample data

Comment: So one could help?

Comment: What does the console log with hello give for data?

Answer (score 0):

```
data = data
```

This will not work as you expect.

I would recommend passing the data into your `initMap` method: `initMap(data)`

```
function initMap(data) {    

  //response from URL have to be used here
  data.forEach((item) => {

    });
}
```

Comment: What is inside your data variable? have you removed the var data? Maybe your data is no array but a normal object

Answer (score 0):

You would be better using a construct like this so you're not using a global variable, that's frowned upon.  using a top level global variable like data you could stomp on any other modules that are using a global data variable (they shouldn't be, but...).  Also, the line `data = data` is not going to assign to the global data variable, since the data variable that's in scope is the one inside the done block (I changed it to then()).

```
$.getJSON("http://XXX?callback=?").then(function( data ) {
    console.log('hello', data);
    initMap(data);
});

function initMap(data) {    

  //response from URL have to be used here
  data.forEach((item) => {

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to loop through JSON:

```js
var tableRow = '';
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/?&results=50&inc=name,email',
  method: 'GET',
  success: function(data) {
  var items = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
      items += '<tr><td>' + data.results[i].name.first + ' ' + data.results[i].name.last + '</td><td>' + data.results[i].email + '</td><td>' + data.results[i].email + '</td></tr>';
    }
          $("#dataTable tbody").html(items);
          console.log(data);

  },
  error: function() {
    var tableRow = '<tr><td>There is no data to display</td></tr>';
    console.log(tableRow);
    $("#dataTable tbody").html(tableRow);

  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table" id="dataTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Full Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have update my question by adding full script, please have a look